# Magento 2 prevent function from executing using plugins

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, module, plugin

There is a third party module which contain the RecurringData.php file.

That class has install function which runs **$this->testimonial->update();** function. I want to stop the execution of that function. I don't want          $this->testimonial->update(); to execute.

```
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $setup->startSetup();

     $this->testimonial->update();

    $setup->endSetup();
}
```

I am not sure which plugin would be the right fit for this.  how can I skip this function execution using plugin?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You should better use preference to achieve this instead of plugin. As original method is going to be executed in any type of plugin (after,before,aroung).

Comment: can we not modify it using around?

Comment: Check this https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html#prioritizing-plugins